# Параллельность PHP

Tags: php, многопоточность, асинхронность

Как реализовать параллельные запросы с помощью pthreads php?

Все статьи, которые нашел на английском.

Подскажите, как сделать простенький многопоточный скрипт например с `file_get_contents('//test.ru');`

Comment: https://blog.programster.org/ubuntu16-04-compile-php-7-2-with-pthreads

Comment: https://reactphp.org ? или вам именно pthreads? есть ещё proc_open http://php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php

Comment: а можно поподробнее reactphp? как установить и если можно простенький пример как запустить

Comment: https://gist.github.com/VarunBatraIT/b87790aaf76f3d56da73d1195aceed89#file-php7_pthreads_en-sh

Comment: https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/861

Answer (score 1):

Многопоточность доступна лишь тогда, когда на сервере больше одного ядра. Воспользуйтесь мульти `cUrl`'ом. Это будет быстрей чем `file_get_contents`. Есть хорошая [статья](http://stupid.su/php-curl_multi/) на эту тему. Ниже привожу пример многопоточного `cUrl`:

```
<?php
$urls = array(
    'http://graph.facebook.com/http://tech.vg.no',
    'http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.vg.no',
);

$multi = curl_multi_init();
$channels = array();

foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_multi_add_handle($multi, $ch);

    $channels[$url] = $ch;
}

$active = null;
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($multi, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($multi) == -1) {
        continue;
    }

    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($multi, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}

foreach ($channels as $channel) {
    echo curl_multi_getcontent($channel);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($multi, $channel);
}

curl_multi_close($multi);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как реализовать параллельные запросы с помощью pthreads php?

### Начнем с установки, путь composer:

1. Установить [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)
2. `composer require krakjoe/pthreads-polyfill`
3. Добавить в файл `require_once("vendor/autoload.php");`
4. `php -f your-file.php`

---

### Простенький многопоточный скрипт:

```php
    <?php
    require_once("vendor/autoload.php");  // Если через composer 

    class WebWorker extends Worker {
        public function run(){}
    }

    class WebRequest extends Threaded {
        public $url;
        public $data;

        public function __construct($url) {
            $this->url = $url;
        }

        public function run() {
            $response = file_get_contents($this->url);

            if ($response) {
                /* обработка ответа */
                $this->data = $response;
            }
        }
    }

    $worker = new WebWorker();
    $worker->start();

    $work = array();

    /* содание рандомной работы  */
    foreach (range(0, 10) as $index) {
        /* сохраняет ссылку  */
        $work[$index] = new WebRequest(
            "http://pthreads.org/?query={$index}");

        /* создает стек процессов на выполнение */
        $worker->stack($work[$index]);
    }


    /* Гасит все предыдущие ожидающие процессы, 
         которые были в стеке
        продолжает работу
     */
    $worker->shutdown();
     // Вывод того что получилось
    foreach ($work as $task) {
        var_dump ($task->data);
```

---

[Офф. Сайт](http://pthreads.org/)

---